# How to pass the listid to servlet when I click a hyperlink in jsp

Tags: html

I have a list of items being displayed in a html table, where there is a hyperlink in every row.

When I click the hyperlink, I want to call the servlet with that particular item id.

how can i achieve it?

for 10 items.

```
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="" value="%=request.getAttribute("item_id")%>"
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <font> (String)providerDetail.get("tripTime")<font />
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <font>(String) providerDetail.get("noOfSeats")</font>
      <td align="center">
        <font> <a href="./selectprovider"> Select font </a></font>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

endfor

So, when I click the hyperlink, I need to pass the appropriate item_id to the servlet.
How to have the appropriate input element for the running item_id and to pass the same to servlet?

I am not being able to add html elements as it is not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

On assumption you are using ajax, `onclick` call a javascript method, pass item_id as parameter to that method.

Then send this to your server as data (I am using jQuery to do this, you can use any other library )

```
function sendData(item_id){
    jQuery.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      data:"itemId="+item_id,
      success: function(data){
       //Your code for a successful request goes here.
      },
      error: function(data){
        //Errors treatment goes here.
      }
    })
}
```

In case you are doing something like download of a document based on the item id, this is a good example code for that:

```
var form = '<form action="downloadme"><input type="hidden" name="itemid" value='+item_id+'</form>';
jQuery(form).submit();
```

Create a form and submit it, and as an hidden parameter pass item_id.
On completion remove that form from body(as you do not need it anymore).

Hope this helps.